# How to make VS Code show error in JS ES6 class?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, visual-studio-code

I have two modules in one folder, mod1.js:

```
'use strict';

export class MyClass {
    constructor() {

    }
    lala() {
         alert(1);
     }
}
```

And mod2.js:

```
'use strict';
import {MyClass} from './mod1';

let c = new MyClass();
c.lala2(); //HERE I WANT TO SEE ERROR
```

The problem is that Visual Studio Code doesn't show error in mod2. How to make it show the error, if it is possible?

Comment: I don't think visual studio (I don't use it) has a complete JavaScript analyzer. JavaScript is very flexible in such things which makes it very difficult to filter errors without directly running it...

Comment: @E730: VSCode has a very good JS analyzer. But I don't think it's up to this, sadly.

Comment: @Pavel - Not an answer (hence commenting), but VSCode does this out of the box if you use TypeScript. It even shows you an error from the TypeScript compiler: "Property 'lala2' does not exist on type 'MyClass'. Did you mean 'lala'?" (Note: I'm not saying "use TypeScript" and I don't currently use it. Just pointing out the option.)

Comment: `c.lala2()` is not necessarily an error, because the functions of an object can be extended at any time. In the simple case you show here where `constructor` is empty, and `let c = new MyClass()` is right before `c.lala2()` then it would be possible to check. But in most cases a simple static analysis would not allow to check if `c.lala2()` is an error.

Comment: Pavel_K - Only if you want to use it, [TypeScript](http://typescriptlang.org) is a tool, and like most tools has pros and cons. It's a layer on top of JavaScript adding a static type system. As @t.niese says, JavaScript is very dynamic. TypeScript intentionally reins that in a bit (although you can always break out).

Comment: @Pavel_K I don't think you can use TS tools to do this. The tools that add type checking to JS like TypeScript, Flow or others, do this by extending the language (`let c:MyClass  = new MyClass()`) or using comments and only this additional information would allow those tools do more test.

Comment: @t.niese: Actually, if you treat the posted code as TypeScript with no text changes at all, it flags this up. TypeScript can do a lot of inferring. :-)

Comment: @Pavel_K: If you ran the TypeScript compiler on your code, it would be able to infer a lot (for instance, the specific thing above) even with no code changes, but it would also miss a lot, so probably not useful. For instance, if you passed `c` into a function as `c2` without any type annotation, it wouldn't know `c2` doesn't have `lala2`. So if you really want this kind of rigorous API check, it may be worth the cost of adopting TypeScript, as this really is its raison d'être. But probably not without adopting it properly. Again: Static analysis of JS code only gets you so far. :-) Good luck!